# How can I determine a correlation from 2 metric variables?

Tags: statistics, spss

I would like to know how to find a correlation of 2 metric variables in SPSS.

I have to find a correlation between the "Number of borrowed cars (metric)"
and the "Temperature(Metric)" at a certain "Daytime (Nominal)" = 8pm. Unfortunately, I do not have the experience in statistics to know with which analysis I can work this case. Does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you the correlation for every separate value of `Daytime`:

```
sort cases by Daytime.
split file by Daytime.
correlations Ncars with Temperature.
split file off.
```

If you only want the value for 8pm, you can use `filter`:

```
compute filt = (Daytime = 8).
filter by filt.
correlations Ncars with Temperature.
filter off.
```

If you don't want the filter to be temporary, you can use `select if Daytime = 8.` .